# reading redundant xml tags in java

Tags: java, xml

I want to read an xml file like

```
<config>
<name>empData</name>
<employee>
<emp-name>Tom</emp-name>
<emp-age>25</emp-age>
<emp-lang>English</emp-lang>
<emp-lang>French</emp-lang>
</employee>
</config>
```

can have more than 1 employee and each employee can have more than 1 tag.
I want to store each employee's data in a list.
How can I do the same.

I am using

```
for(int j=0;j<lengthHeader;j++){
xmlDataModel = new XMLDataModel();

                                                    xmlDataModel.setEmpLang( e.getElementsByTagName("emp-lang").item(k).getChildNodes().item(j).getNodeValue());

}
```

where k is the variable for employee tag and j is for emp laguage tag.
with this it is retrieving only 1st value and after that it is throwing null pointer exception and if I use item(j).item(0) ,then it is retrieving emp-lang for all employees,I want only for each employee tag separately.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to use some parser like JAXB for doing this. http://javapapers.com/jee/jaxb-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Is it possible to do like this only because I am reading big xml file dynamically and have done front end coding with this only and I need to complete it by today.